# Calculating the signature of matrix A?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, bilinear-form

given is a symmetrical bilinearform s that has the following matrix:

$A = M_\beta(s) = \begin{pmatrix} -3&0&-1\\0&-3&0\\-1&0&-1\end{pmatrix}$

I have to calculate the signature of s and tell, whether s is positive-definite, negative-definite or indefinite.

I take a look at $det(A-t\cdot E_n)$ and get three eigenvalues $< 0$. This means:

Signature $\sigma(s) = (3,0,0)$ and the matrix is positive definite, right?

Comment: How can a square matrix be positive definite when it has nonpositive diagonal entries?!

Comment: Note that the eigenvalues of $I_n$ are all positive, and the corresponding bilinear form is positive definite.

Comment: Hi user1551: I meant negative definite

@Travis ?

Comment: @Vazrael Yes, that's right. Note that in practice people often simply write signature as a pair $(p, q)$ indicating "the number of positive and negative directions" when the bilinear form is understood from context to be nondegenerate.

Comment: @Vazrael If you meant "negative definite" then edit accordingly your question

Comment: Does this answer your question? [determine signature of matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/988814/determine-signature-of-matrix)

Answer (score 1):

Another way following "the path of Sylvester's Theorem":

$$\begin{pmatrix} -3&0&-1\\0&-3&0\\-1&0&-1\end{pmatrix}\stackrel{R_1\leftrightarrow R_3}\rightarrow\begin{pmatrix} -1&0&-1\\0&-3&0\\-3&0&-1\end{pmatrix}\stackrel{C_1\leftrightarrow C_3}\rightarrow\begin{pmatrix} -1&0&-1\\0&-3&0\\-1&0&-3\end{pmatrix}\stackrel{R_3-R_1}\rightarrow$$

$$\begin{pmatrix} -1&0&-1\\0&-3&0\\0&0&-2\end{pmatrix}\stackrel{C_3-C_1}\rightarrow\begin{pmatrix} -1&0&0\\0&-3&0\\0&0&-2\end{pmatrix}$$

So we got a diagonal matrix congruent to  the original one all of which diagonal elements are negative, and thus the signature is $\;(0,3)\;$ and the matrix is negative definite.

Comment: What are the first two steps for?

Comment: Well, the first step is to make things a little easier, and the second one **must** be there as to get congruent matrices we must do on columns exactly what we do on rows.

Comment: Given that the first two steps just turn the matrix upside down, I don't see how they make anything easier.

Comment: For me it is easier to substract three times the first row from the last one , rather than  one third of the first row from the last one. Matter of taste.

Comment: But is it also easier to subtract three times the first row from the last one, than it is to subtract three times the last row from the first one?

Comment: I reduce matrices from top to bottom and not the other way around. I think most people does the same.